# cascading second selectonemenu not calling the setter

Tags: ajax, validation, jsf, drop-down-menu, primefaces

After selecting the system(the first selectonemenu), I see that the dropdown of section is populated, but when I select the section, I do not see the setter being called. and hence though I submit the form , I am getting Validation Error Value is not valid.

```
<h:outputText value="System" />  
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{moduleManagementController.selectedSystem}" converter="#{applicationSystemConverter}">  
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />  
    <f:selectItems value="#{applicationSystems}" var="appsystem" itemLabel="#{appsystem.name}" itemValue="#{appsystem}"/>
    <p:ajax event="change" update="section" listener="#{moduleManagementController.onApplicationSystemChanged}"/>  
</p:selectOneMenu> 

<h:outputText value="Section" />  
<p:selectOneMenu id="section" value="#{moduleManagementController.newModule.section}" converter="#{systemSectionConverter}">  
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />  
    <f:selectItems value="#{moduleManagementController.assignableSysSections}" var="section" itemLabel="#{section.name}" itemValue="#{section}"/>  
    <p:ajax event="change" update="addModule"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Following is my SystemSection's equals method

```
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(this == obj) {
        return true;
    } if(obj == null) {
        return false;
    } if(! this.getId().equals(((SystemSection)obj).getId())) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

my converter class :

```
@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        String value) {
     if(value == null || "".equals(value)) {
         return null;
     }
     try {
         SystemSection section = systemSectionRepo.findById(Long.valueOf(value));
         return section;
     } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
         return null;
     }
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see javax.faces.convert.Converter#getAsString(javax.faces.context.FacesContext, javax.faces.component.UIComponent, java.lang.Object)
 */
@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        Object value) {  

     if (value instanceof SystemSection)
     {
         return ((SystemSection)value).getId().toString();
     }   
     return "";
}
```

I am not sure what is going wrong. One thing I understood is the equals method is returning false and hence the setter method is not being called. can some one please help me solve the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure but it looks like the error is in the `getAsObject` method. It would be good to debug the converter, especially the `String value` parameter value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I noticed that the getasObject is not being invoked in this process , but its calling getasstring

Comment: The getAsObject is called on submit and the value is empty. Not sure why there is an empty value. i have been working on this since 2days with no progress.

Comment: It would be better to isolate the problem: create a single page where you only have this list and try to submit a value in it. Make all the debug and everything else you need to find the problem. Sorry for not could do more than just giving advices =\.

Answer (score 0):

> *I am getting Validation Error Value is not valid.*

You will get this error when `equals()` test of the selected item has not returned `true` for any of the currently available items during processing of the form submit.

So, this can have 2 causes, or 3 if a converter is involved:

1. The `equals()` is missing or broken.
2. The list of currently available items has incompatibly changed during the request of processing of the form submit as compared to the request of displaying the form.
3. The converter did not return the right submitted value on `getAsObject()`.

The `equals()` method and the converter seem to look fine. Left behind cause 2. To the point, the list behind `#{moduleManagementController.assignableSysSections}` has incompatibly changed. Apparently your bean is request scoped or you're performing business logic in the getter method. Putting the bean in the view scope and making sure that you aren't doing business logic in the getter method should fix it.

Comment: I tried with the ViewScope ,but I am still getting the error.